# Unable to find build script on CloudBees Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, salesforce, cloudbees

Getting the following error on Jenkins hosted by CloudBees:

```
FATAL: Unable to find build script at /scratch/jenkins/workspace/PROJECTNAME/deploy_ci/build.xml deploy
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

That is executed by the following configuration in Jenkins

```
Build
Invoke Ant
Targets: -lib deploy_ci/lib/ant-salesforce.jar
Build File: deploy_ci/build.xml deploy
```

I can confirm that I have /deploy_ci/build.xml in my git repo.

If I'm doing something dumb, great.  If there is a way to troubleshoot this more effectively on jenkins or cloudbees (new to both), I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the `deploy` belongs in *Targets*, not *Build File*.